# How to send message to youtube user using youtube API?

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api, author

I am developing a script to send a message to a YouTube user.  Actually, I have got the YouTube data feeds with the information - YouTube video id, author name, details etc.., for that corresponding author. I have to send a message using the YouTube api.  Is this possible?

I have already written Oauth login and YouTube API feed to get video and user information for that corresponding video.  I referred to this documentation in the YouTube API - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages#Sending_a_message for send message, but there are no options for this. There are only options to send message as comments instead of new mail to the inbox of the corresponding video author.

So please update me if you know about that.  I have pasted my script below.

```
 $developer_key='###########################';
    $client_id=     '#################';
    $client_secret='#################';

    // error checking; user might have denied access
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        if ($_GET['error'] == 'access_denied') {
            echo('You have denied access. Click <a href="'. $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] .'">here</a> to retry&hellip;');
        } else {
            echo("An error has occurred: ". $_GET['error']);
        }
        exit;
    }

    // Step 1: redirect to google account login if necessary
    if(!isset($_GET['code']) || $_GET['code'] === '') { 
        Header('Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id='. $client_id .
                '&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest%2Foauth_1.php' .
                '&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline',
            true, 307);
        exit;
    }
    $authorization_code= $_GET['code'];

    // Step 2: use authorization code to get access token
    $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    $message_post= 'code='. $authorization_code .
            '&client_id='. $client_id . 
            '&client_secret='. $client_secret .
            '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/test/oauth_1.php' .
            '&grant_type=authorization_code';


    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message_post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($cur_error= curl_error($ch)) {
        echo($cur_error);
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $jsonArray= json_decode($result, true);

    if ($jsonArray === null) {
        echo("Could not decode JSON.");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($jsonArray['error'])) {
        echo("An error has occurred: ". $jsonArray['error']);
        exit;
    }

    if (!isset($jsonArray['access_token'])) {
        echo("Access token not found.");
        exit;
    }


    //The user's authentication token
     $access_token= $jsonArray['access_token'];
    $title ='krishna'; //The title of the caption track
    $lang = 'en'; //The languageof the caption track
    //$transcript = $_REQUEST['transcript']; //The caption file data
    $ur='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/recepient_username/inbox';



    $headers = array(

         'Host: gdata.youtube.com',
        'Content-Type: application/atom+xml utf-8',
        'Content-Language: ' . $lang,
        'Slug: ' . rawurlencode($title),
        'Authorization: AuthSub token=' . $access_token,
        'GData-Version: 2',
        'X-GData-Key: key=' . $developer_key
    );


    $xml = '&xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
      <id>cSVSeHFKBjU</id>
      <summary>sending a message from the api</summary>
    </entry>';
    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($xml) );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

    $tt = curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($tt);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);


    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

echo "DONE! Token:" . $access_token . "<br />\n";
var_dump($result);
```

SO please check and update me if there any options to send mail to the video user instead of comments.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube v2.0 API does support sending new messages to a user's inbox, but the message must contain both a video and a comment about that video. You cannot send a text-only message.

Documentation, which includes a use case explaining how YouTube's messaging support is intended to be used, can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages?hl=en#Sending_a_message).